# PHP: How to convert comma separated strings of grade levels to english-readable "grade ranges"?

Tags: php, regex, csv, explode

I have a string (not an array) of grade levels for a student. Here are some examples of possible entries:

```
k,1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4
1
1,2
3,4,5
```

Maximum grade level for a student is 5.

I want to convert the string to an english readable range. So given my above examples, this would be the output:

```
K & Up
1-4
1
1 & 2
3 & Up
```

How best to handle this? Examples are appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
function toRange($string)
{
$min = "K";
$max = 5;

//take string and turn into an array
$grades = explode(", ",$string);
$firstItem = $grades[0];
$lastItem = $grades[count($grades)-1];
if (count($grades) == 1)
{
  $output = $firstItem;
}
else
{
    if ($firstItem == "K")
    {
        if ($lastItem == 5)
        {
          $output = "K & Up";
        }
        if ($lastItem == 1)
        {
            $output = "K & 1";
        }
        else {
            $output = "K -" . $lastItem;
        }
        break;

    }
    else 
    {
        if ($lastItem == 5)
        {
            if ($firstItem != 4)
            {
                $output = $firstItem . " & Up";
            }
            else {
                $output = "4 & 5";
            }
        }
        else {
            if ($lastItem > $firstItem + 1)
            {
                $output = $firstItem . " - " . $lastItem;
            }
            else {
                $output = $firstItem . " & " . $lastItem;
            }
        }
    }


     }
return $output;
    }


?>
```

This could have been much easier had it not been for the involvement of the letter.

Comment: Thanks! I agree, the letter throws it off. I may have to change the way the data gets in there in the first place to clean it up a bit. I needed to add 1 more if statement to your code to catch for when the grade level is only 1 grade. I added it before all the other ifs: if($lastItem == $firstItem){$output = $firstItem;return $output;}

Comment: On thinking about it now you could simply make the K a 0 during the processing and then change it on the output with str_replace("0","K",$output). Anyway, I have made those changes now in the post, albeit in a different way.

Comment: Yes, was just thinking the same thing about the 0.